# Javascript recursive function not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, recursion, nested

I am trying to write a code to read a nested JSON and print the items. Later I plan to generate a menu from this.

The JSON content is as follows:

```
{
    "label": "Root of Menu",
    "child": [  
            {
            "label": "Menu 1",
            "child": [
                    {
                    "label": "Menu 1.1",
                    "child": [
                            {
                                "label": "Menu 1.1.1"
                            },
                            {
                                "label": "Menu 1.1.2"
                            }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "label": "Menu 1.2",
                    "child": [
                            {
                                "label": "Menu 1.2.1"
                            },
                            {
                                "label": "Menu 1.2.2"
                            }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "label": "Menu 1.3",
                    "child": [
                            {
                                "label": "Menu 1.3.1"
                            },
                            {
                                "label": "Menu 1.3.2"
                            }
                    ]   
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Menu 2",
            "child": [
                    {
                        "label": "Menu 2.1"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Menu 2.2"
                    }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Menu 3",
            "child": 
                    {   
                        "label": "Menu 3.1"
                    }
        }
    ]   
}
```

I am using the following recursive function:

```
function menuize(m) { 
    if (m instanceof Array) {
        for(i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            for(p in m[i]) {
                menuize(m[i][p]);
            }
        }           
    } else if (m instanceof Object) {
        for(p in m) {
                menuize (m[p]);                 
        }

    } else {
        console.log('Label: ' + m);
    }

}
```

The `menuize(m)` call starts with `m` being the JSON object evaluated using `JSON.parse(XHR.responseText)` where XHR is the `XMLHttpRequest` object used to retrieve the data. I've seen that the data is read completely fine so that is not the problem.

Now, what happens is that the function works somewhat correct, in terms that it works fine till it reaches the innermost `child` but after that, it does not get back to properly printing the rest of the items one level up and so on.

The output generated will help you to understand what is happening:

```
t: Root of Menu 
t: Menu 1
t: Menu 1.1
t: Menu 1.1.1
t: Menu 1.1.2
```

I can't understand what exactly is happening and why shouldn't the items like `Menu 1.2`, `Menu 2` (which are relatively in the upper levels) be printed.

Would someone please be kind to provide some insight and help me understand? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your iteration variables need to be declared with `var` so they'll be local variables. Otherwise, when you recurse, you're overwriting the variables used in the caller.

```
function menuize(m) { 
    var i, p;
    if (m instanceof Array) {
        for(i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            for(p in m[i]) {
                menuize(m[i][p]);
            }
        }           
    } else if (m instanceof Object) {
        for(p in m) {
                menuize (m[p]);                 
        }

    } else {
        console.log('Label: ' + m);
    }

}
```